# Definition of " How Shakespearian"

Tags: meaning, idioms, meaning-in-context, lexicon

Could you explain what " How Shakespearian" means?

I've heard it recently but I can't remember in which situation the phrase was used.

Comment: Was it used as a question or as a comment? That could help someone answer.

Answer (score 2):

As an adjective, **Shakespearean** could refer to a specialization or a style of writing.  If you <strike>where</strike> were a scholar and specialized in the writing of Shakespeare, you would be a *Shakespearean scholar*.

The fragment *how Shakespearean,* depending on additional context, would be used to describe the writing of a work that resembled Shakespeare's style.
 Within in a vaudevillian context it might appear thusly:

Comic:  *I am soooo Shakespearean.*
Straight man: *How Shakespearean are you?*
Comic: *I am so Shakespearean that when I make a ham omelette, I call it a Hamlet.*

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Thanks!......I made the correction.

Comment: It's *ShakespearIAN* oops, there are two spellings. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Shakespearian

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Done!